# What is this type of delegate called(C#)

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, anonymous-delegates

I have these lines of code.

```
class Program
{
    public delegate void printer();

    public static void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        printer del = delegate { Method(); };
        del();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Now what do i call this statement `printer del = delegate { Method(); };`.

Surely it cant be called anonymous method because here i have a named method.

Comment: It's an anonymous method that happens to call another method. You could put other statements in there if you'd like.

Comment: FYI there isn't really a need to create your own delegate with the signature of `void` and no parameters.  You can just use `Action`, as defined by the language, for such delegates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an anonymous delegate who's only function happens to be calling a named method.

Answer (score 9):

It's called an [Anonymous method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Surely it can't be called anonymous method because here I have a named method

It's still an anonymous method, as @Daniel pointed out in the comments what your doing is instantiating an instance of the `printer` delegate by assigning a method with the same signature (which happens to be...an anonymous method). You could avoid using an anonymous method completely by doing:

```
Printer del = Method;
```

Comment: -1: "How would the compiler know that the above code should use the named method printer?" - there is no named method `printer`. `printer` is the delegate type and the assignment creates a new delegate of that type.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth was actually correcting that as you commented!

Comment: It's still wrong, sorry. My previous comment explains why. You are mixing delegate *type* and delegate *instance* here. `printer` is the type, `del` an instance of that type.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth does that make more sense? I actually missed the part in the code where the OP was doing `Printer del ...`.

Comment: Hm, now your answer is basically saying: "It is still an anonymous method because it is an anonymous method" - that's circular reasoning. Basically, that he is using the `printer` delegate is irrelevant here. Relevant is simply that he is creating a new method without a name. This method can only be called with the delegate it is assigned to. It can't be called on any class instance or on any static class. That's why it is an anonymous method.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I get what your saying...but that's obviously not what I meant. I was saying the bit of code is *still* an anonymous method, but it's being used to create an instance of a named delegate.

Comment: I am not sure how the named delegate is relevant here but that's not important. As you can see, I already removed my downvote. BTW: Your code sample would not be an anonymous method ;-)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth yeah the code sample was just to illustrate that it's the same scenario without an anon delegate. Thanks :)

Comment: It's no problem that `Method` is static. He **can** say: `printer del = Method;` In that case his `printer` instance will point directly to the ordinary method. When he uses the anonymous method (or equivalently a lambda arrow) the delegate instance will of course refer the anonymous method (whose "body" (the block in braces `{}`) can hold almost any code he wishes).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen AFAIK you can't assign static methods to delegates (at least in that way)

Comment: @James Have you tried? A delegate can reference an instance method or a static method (or a whole invocation list of methods some of which may be static). The [`Target` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.target.aspx) is `null` if and only if the (last) method represented by the delegate is a `static` method. The notation `printer del = Method;` in C# 2.0 and later is called "method group conversion" and is equivalent to `var del = new printer(Method);`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen nope not ever had the need to but pretty sure I read that you can't do it (at least using the syntax in my answer). I am not in front of a machine but I can check it out

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - Your spot on, I clearly misread that. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's an anonymous method, as the others have said.

You could also accomplish the same thing with this code:

```
Action del = () => Method();
del();
```

This way, you don't need to define the `delegate` and use the built-in `Action` type.

Answer (score 1):

It's an anonymous method. The inside of the method does call a named one but that doesn't change the fact that the outher method is anonymous.

You can easily see this when you would expand del:

```
class Program
{
    public delegate void printer();

    public static void MethodA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }

    public static void MethodB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("World");
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool x = true;

        printer del = delegate 
        {
            if (x)
            {
                MethodA();
            }
            else
            {
                MethodB();
            }
        };

        del();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use a delegate you could do the same with an Action:

```
   Action delA = () => MethodA();
   delA();
```

`Action` points to a void returning method that takes no parameters.